# Regex to match if a string contains another string preceded by dot, space or nothing and followed by space, hyphen or nothing

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a string starts, ends with the searched string or contains the searched strings preceded by:

- one or more alphabet characters and a space
- one or more alphabet characters plus a point

And followed by s, hyphen, or space and  alphanumeric characters.

If the searched keyword is **Hansen**:

- These are the cases that should match.

```
const shouldMatchCases = [
  "Hansen",
  "Studio Hansen"
  "Hansen-studio",
  "Hansen studio",
  "N.Hansen studio",
  "N.Hansen-studio",
  "N Hansens studio",
  "N Hansen studio",
];
```

- These are the case that should not match.

```
const shouldNotMatchCases = [
  "Hansenssutdio",
  "Hansenstest",
  "Hansenxxx",
  "NormanHansen",
  ".Hansen-studio",
  "Hansen-"
];
```

I have tried this regex, but it does not matche `Hansen` and `Studio Hansen` and matches `.Hansen-studio` that it must not do.

```
  const regex = new RegExp(`(?:\\b|^)(?:[A-Za-z]+\\.)?(${etternavn})s?(-|\\s)[A-Za-z0-9]+`)
```

```js
function matchesPattern(str, keyword) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`(?:\\b|^)(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)?(${keyword})s?(-|\\s)[A-Za-z0-9]+`)
  return regex.test(str);
}
// Test cases that should match
const shouldMatchCases = [
  "Hansen",
  "Test Hansen",
  "Hansen-studio",
  "Hansen studio",
  "N.Hansen studio",
  "N.Hansen-studio",
  "N Hansens studio",
  "N Hansen studio",
];
// Test cases that should not match
const shouldNotMatchCases = [
  "Hansenssutdio",
  "Hansenstest",
  "Hansenxxx",
  "NormanHansen",
  ".Hansen-studio",
  "Hansen-"
];
// Test with dynamic keyword
const keyword = "Hansen";
console.log(`Testing with keyword: '${keyword}' for expected matches:`);
shouldMatchCases.forEach(str => {
  console.log(`${str}: ${matchesPattern(str, keyword)}`);
});
console.log(`\nTesting with keyword: '${keyword}' for expected non-matches:`);
shouldNotMatchCases.forEach(str => {
  console.log(`${str}: ${matchesPattern(str, keyword)}`);
});
```

Comment: Maybe all you need is `\bHansens?\b`? ``new RegExp(`\\b${keyword}s?\\b`)``? Looks like you want to match a whole word with an optional Plural. So, I'd rather use  `(?:e?s)?` instead of `s?`. Note `(?:\\b|^)` = `\\b` in this context when the next char is a word char.

Comment: Well, your requirements can be implemented as ``new RegExp(`(?<=\\p{L}(?:\\s+|\\.\\s*)|^)Hansen(?=(?:e?s)?\\b|[\\-\\s]|$)`, `u`)``, but it looks cumbersome. You need to try these out on your data, I guess you have many more test cases.

Comment: Thanks. It is genitive s, and it could be any words instead of Hansen for example Steve Mahan

Comment: `\bHansens?\b` matches `.Hansen`. But I want to only match if it is preceded by one or more alphanumeric characters and a dot.

Comment: So try ``new RegExp(`(?<=\\p{L}(?:\\s+|\\.\\s*)|^)${keyword}(?=s?\\b|[-\\s]|$)`, `u`)``

Comment: It is almost perfect. It matches `Hansen-`.  I want to match only if there is at least one alphanumeric characters after the hyphen. If there is `s`, hyphen or a space after the search keyword, there must be at least one alphanumeric character followed by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
new RegExp(String.raw`(?<=\p{L}(?:\s+|\.\s*)|^)${keyword}(?:s?[-\s]\p{L}|$)`, `u`)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3XdHKR/4). Mind the `u` flag.

*Details*

- `(?<=\p{L}(?:\s+|\.\s*)|^)` - at the start of string (`^`), or right after a Unicode letter (`\p{L}`) that is followed with either one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) or a dot and zero or more whitespaces (`\.\s*`)
- `Hansen` - the keyword and then
- `(?:s?[-\s]\p{L}|$)` - an optional `s` and then either a `-` or whitespace and a Unicode letter (`s?[-\s]\p{L}`), or end of string (`$`).

```js
function matchesPattern(str, keyword) {
  const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`(?<=\p{L}(?:\s+|\.\s*)|^)${keyword}(?:s?[-\s]\p{L}|$)`, `u`)
  return regex.test(str);
}
// Test cases that should match
const shouldMatchCases = [
  "Hansen",
  "Test Hansen",
  "Hansen-studio",
  "Hansen studio",
  "N.Hansen studio",
  "N.Hansen-studio",
  "N Hansens studio",
  "N Hansen studio",
];
// Test cases that should not match
const shouldNotMatchCases = [
  "Hansenssutdio",
  "Hansenstest",
  "Hansenxxx",
  "NormanHansen",
  ".Hansen-studio",
  "Hansen-",
  "Hansens"
];
// Test with dynamic keyword
const keyword = "Hansen";
console.log(`Testing with keyword: '${keyword}' for expected matches:`);
shouldMatchCases.forEach(str => {
  console.log(`${str}: ${matchesPattern(str, keyword)}`);
});
console.log(`\nTesting with keyword: '${keyword}' for expected non-matches:`);
shouldNotMatchCases.forEach(str => {
  console.log(`${str}: ${matchesPattern(str, keyword)}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is almost perfect.  There must be at least one alphanumeric character after s. Hence, I do not match `Hansens` because there is not any alphanumeric characters after of it.

Comment: @mahan Try the updated version.

Comment: I want to extend this regex to match `Hansen & Johnsen studio`. It should match Hansen if it is followed by a space,  &, space, and alphanumeric characters

Comment: @mahan Try replacing `[-\s]` with `[-&\s]*`.

Comment: I did it. But it matches `Hansens`. It does not match if there a space around the ampersand as in `Hansen & Johnsen` studio.

Comment: @mahan Right, replace `*` with `+`, `[-&\s]+`

Comment: It works. But there must be a space around the ampersand.

Comment: @mahan then use `(?<=\p{L}(?: +|\. *)|^)Hansen(?:s?(?:[- ]|\s+&\s+)\p{L}|$)`, see https://regex101.com/r/3XdHKR/5

Comment: Can it be done without using the lookbehind assertion?

Comment: @mahan Yes, replace `(?<=` with `(?:`

Comment: I need to match only if there is a single space before the dot. I tried to add a  `\s` after `\.` but it did not work. Could you help?

Comment: @mahan No idea what you mean. There is no space before the dot anywhere in the examples.